# WindowsReport exporting to pdf, bad formatting

Tags: c#, reporting-services, reporting, report

HI,
I have a windows report. 
I am passing into textbox in report(rdlc) multi value address.
and the exported PDF I receive text slightly distorted.

as:

```
ReportParameter Address = new ReportParameter("Address", 
                          new string[] { 
                              "Mickey Mouse\r\n", 
                              "Flat No. 0\r\n", 
                              "18 Adress\r\n", 
                              "London\r\n", 
                              "United Kingdom\r\n", 
                              "A12 234L" });
```

However,
 after exporting the file into PDF i receive the text slightly distorted.

I got it formated as follows:

```
Mickey Mouse
 Flat No. 0
 18 Adress
 London
 United Kingdom
 A12 234L
```

Any ideas why is that?

The textbox definition is:

```
<Textbox Name="Adress">
    <Top>5.1cm</Top>
    <Width>6.55cm</Width>
    <Style>
      <TextAlign>Left</TextAlign>
      <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
      <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
      <Language>en-GB</Language>
    </Style>
    <ZIndex>2</ZIndex>
    <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
    <Left>0.8cm</Left>
    <Height>2.94999cm</Height>
    <Value>=Join(Parameters!Address.Value)</Value>
  </Textbox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

stoped to using text box and used table instead, and i have no problem with formating any more